# Windows updates in WSUS - how to determine which KB is for which windows version?

Tags: windows, wsus, windows-update, wsus-offline

I would like to automate the distribution of updates from my Master WSUS to offline branch servers using scripts, but not in all branches we have all windows versions and I would like only distribute relevant updates to each branch server. The problem is we will then have to manually maintain a file or table which determines which KB is for which version so this can't be fully automated. It would be great to find some online DB or even web-page I could easily query to get this up to date information or solve this in another way. I found no solutions searching online. Do you have any ideas?

WSUS built in downstream replica is not possible in our environment - isolated sites with file transfer through dedicated secure file transfer system.

Comment: TBH, instead of making things more complicated than they need to be, why don't you use WSUS in the way it was designed to work and just set up downstream WSUS replica partners and let them get all of the updates from the parent WSUS server?

Comment: Because it is not possible in our environment - isolated sites with file transfer through dedicated secure file transfer system - i'll add it in the post.